# Switching between connections on a hyper-v machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v

i have a OS Host connected to the internet with Ethernet 'and sometimes there's a DSL cable connected to this host' and on this host there's a VM running, and  i would like to configure the VM to be able to switch between DSL and Ethernet upon request but the Host itself shouldn't get the DSL connection when i plug in the DSL cabel, just the VM. 'so to sum up: Host is in privtae network but the VM on this host should be able to switch between Private Network and DSL'

is it possible? if yes i would really appreciate an answer and if my question lacks info or effort i'm sorry, let me know and i'll change it.

thanks

Comment: How is the DSL cable connected, exactly? Does the host have a built-in DSL modem, or are you using an external modem through Ethernet?

Comment: Thank you for replying, i am using an external modem through Ethernet to connect the DSL cable

Comment: Does the host have multiple Ethernet ports, then? (Sounds like you're using one for 'regular' Internet connection and another for DSL modem?)

Comment: No the host has only one Ethernet port but i'm using a USB 3.0 to Ethernet adapter to connect the DSL cable to the host. sorry should've added this earlier to the post